# Why is my linear-background acting like this?

Tags: html, css

I literally wrote one line of code to style my background and it doesn't work. My background is supposed to be a liner-gradient going from the top left to the bottom right. It does do this but has rows of red in blue in between each other going down. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhRPZ.jpg)I used the colors red and blue. Can someone please help me?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red, blue);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to bottom right?

Comment: it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You haven't given the body a minimum height but the html element is taking up the body background as it hasn't been given a background of its own - and the default background-repeat is to repeat.  Hence lots of stripes. Try giving body min-height: 100vh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, red, blue);
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>Linear Gradient Background</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, would you mind explaining how it works?

Answer (score 0):

because the default height of the body is zero and you're making the gradient go to the top it gives this glitching effect because it's repeating as A Haworth said in the reply

> the html element picks up the background of the body if it doesn't have one set for itself and repeat is the default setting for background-repeat.

if you set the direction to Right only it will also repeat but it will not give the border glitch feeling , if you want to know how it would look like without the repeat you can make the CSS code like this

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red, blue);
}
```

it will give the expected behavior with the gradient happening only once.

how to solve this is by giving the screen a height

```
        body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red, blue);
        /* background-repeat: no-repeat !important; this is not 
        needed now */ */
    }
```

this should work just fine

Comment: The explanation of why the gradient was repeated many times is not correct. It had nothing to do with the 'to top' but the html element picks up the background of the body if it doesn't have one set for itself and repeat is the default setting for background-repeat.